# popen in multi-thread c++ server

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, fork, popen

Problem Description:
A multi-threads server is running, with most of the threads serving online requests. Besides, a special thread in charge of monitoring a flag file. If a newer flag file is monitored, which means a new data arrival, then the thread call a function to update the data. In the update func, I use `popen` to call 'wc -l new_data.txt' to get the lines of the new data. But when the `popen` is called , the online requests processing will be hold for several seconds. the phenomenon is observed by several seconds deday in log file. close to the log of `popen` finished, server will write lots of log that indicate many requests are abandoned because of some pooled resources have run out.

Why:
As descripted in the man of [popen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html), its not a block function. But why calling `popen` caused the server process is blocked?

Comment: What is your exact platform? What happens when you monitor the parent process with strace or dtrace through the `popen` - where do the threads block? This could happen because you have a full-fat fork, or a vfork but instantly trigger lots of COW activity, or because you have lots of fds open and cloning _them_ is slow ...

Comment: Oh, and you misunderstood about `popen` not blocking. It just means it (can) return before the child exits. It doesn't affect the fact that forking your whole server process is relatively expensive.

Comment: @Useless on Centos 7. I didn't use strace or dtrace to monitor the parent process, it's a good suggestion. I thought `popen` will use new data/code/stack/heap frame to create a sub process, instead of forking the whole process. In fact, whole process is really heavy, which can be proved by that core file caused by some crash will reach 20G. How can I observe the forking consume caused by `popen`?

Comment: That would be a Windows spawn - no *NIX does that to my knowledge. If you're tracing the process (all threads) when it calls `popen`, you'll see the vfork implemented as a `clone` syscall IIRC.

Comment: BTW, you can avoid this by starting a persistent child process _before_ your parent gets huge, and just ask _that_ to run `wc -l` for you. Or frankly ask it to count newlines itself, it isn't that hard, and almost anything you do is cheaper than forking.

Comment: Thanks, ur comment are on the opposite of ur id. I will try to use perf to catch the syscall IIRC. :)

Comment: In one system that I worked on, the first thing the server process did, _before_ it spawned any threads, was to spawn a helper process. The helper process was strictly single-threaded. After the server was fully up, running with many threads, any time it needed to create a new child process, it would send a message to the helper, asking the helper to do it. In that way, we avoided having to deal with any questions about what really happens when a multi-threaded Linux process calls `fork()`.

Comment: Probably off-topic, but you don't need to spawn a sub-process to count the number of lines in a file.  It would be much more efficient (and about the same amount of coding) to just `fopen()` the file and call `fgets()` in a loop to calculate the number of lines in the file yourself.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Indeed, I'm using `fgets` now.